# json parse error in junit spring test with mokito

Tags: java, json, spring, junit

im trying to create a json to test decode im inserting `new DecodeRequest("a3d3")`
and expecting `DecodeResponse("aaaddd")` in debug mode when i get to `MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();` i recive an error saying *JSON parse error* 
this is my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = Controller.class, secure = false)

public class TestControllerDecodEncode {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Controller controller;

    @Test
    public void decode() throws Exception {
        RequestEntity<DecodeRequest> beenSentToCheck = new RequestEntity<DecodeRequest>(new DecodeRequest("a3d3"),
                HttpMethod.POST, new URI("http://localhost/decode"));

        ResponseEntity<DecodeResponse> answerDecodeShouldBe = new ResponseEntity<DecodeResponse>(
            new DecodeResponse("aaaddd"), HttpStatus.CREATED);

        Mockito.when(controller.DecodeAnswer(beenSentToCheck.getBody())).thenReturn(answerDecodeShouldBe);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/decode").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(answerDecodeShouldBe.toString()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

        assertEquals(answerDecodeShouldBe, response.getStatus());
    }
```

and this is what im testing:

```
@RestController

public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/encode", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ResponseEntity<EncodeResponse> Encodeanswer(@RequestBody EncodeRequest reqEn) {
        String encoded = MyService.encode(reqEn.text);
        return new ResponseEntity<EncodeResponse>(new EncodeResponse(encoded), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

the method been called by the controller **MyService.encode(reqEn.text);** gets astring and return astring.

the two classes decodeRequest and response are :

```
    public class DecodeRequest {
    public   String text;

    public DecodeRequest() {}

    public DecodeRequest(String text) {

        this.text = text;
    };

}



public class DecodeResponse {
     public String decode;

    public DecodeResponse(String decode) {
            this.decode = decode;
    }

    }
```

there is away i can pass the json correctly ? 
i have been sitting on this problem for a day now and would love someone to help me plz . 
lovely day ``

Comment: I am sorry, your code is completely wrong.  the endpoint in controller is `/encode` but from your test class you are calling `/decode`. And also why are you mocking controller. YOu should mock your MyService

Comment: the decode encode was a mistake copying the wront method , its the same on my computre , that was my bad sorry ,first time uploading a question